# After we call list.remove while iterating the arraylist. Elements are not being removed. I got output[2,4]. what is the reason behind it?

Tags: java

```
package com.unisys.geeks.arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.ConcurrentModificationException;
import java.util.List;

public class RemoveElementFromIteration {

    static List<Integer> iterateElements() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            list.remove(i);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            List<Integer> list = iterateElements();
            System.out.print(list);
        }
        catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: was a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException thrown?

Comment: You're calling the `remove(int index)` method, not `remove(Object obj)`. Of course in any case that's not safe, as it's susceptible to `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: No. No exception thrown. I got ouput as [2, 4]. I dont know  why it is removing only odd elements and keeping the even elements. What might be the reason behind it?

Comment: I would like to know why it is keeping the even elements only? why it is removing only odd elements. I didnt put any condition. i just to want to remove all the elements from the list while iterating only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        list.remove(i);
    }
```

Is executed only 2 times, because when you call remove() method, size of a list is decreasing. You can modify it to something like:

```
static List<Integer> iterateElements() {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(4);
    int list_size = list.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < list_size; i++) {
        list.remove(0);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[Oracle says this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-):

> remove(int index)
>
> Removes the element at the specified position in this list (optional operation). Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices). Returns the element that was removed from the list.

```
List = [1,2,3,4]
```

In the first loop count (i = 0), you remove the element on index 0, which in your case is 1.

```
List = [2,3,4]
```

On the second loop count (i = 1), you remove the the element at index 1. But remember that lists are dynamic. So after you removed the Integer 1 in your list. The list changes in size. Now, at index 1, you'll find the Integer 3. After removing the 3, you'll be left with this:

```
List = [2,4]
```

Now, the loops counter will be incremented to 2, making the loop condition false. You'll be left with the list

```
[2,4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. I got the concept now. Thank you very much sir.